# Why does my webcam (light) turn on when i start up my computer after standby?

Tags: 10.10, webcam, lenovo

Hej

When I close my lid on my Lenovo SL500 laptop with in-built webcam, my computer goes on standby. When I start up again the webcam light turns on - for no reason.

I've found a way to make the light turn off again; starting cheese webcam (or probably any other webcam using program) then the light turns off for a second and goes back on, and the program shows camera video. When I close the program the light turns off as well.

Can anybody tell me if my computer is actually turning on the webcam or just the light?
and what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug, and I have the same problem.

Bug report (not mine): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/566205

---

Maybe try `echo 'SUSPEND_MODULES="uvcvideo"' | sudo tee /etc/pm/config.d/modules_unload`? Taken from https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/254825

Comment: what will happen when i type this in?

Comment: It will add the line `SUSPEND_MODULES="uvcvideo"` to `/etc/pm/config.d/modules_unload`. It tells the system to treat the module in a special manner, hopefully fixing the problem.