# Lenovo webcam light stays on after bootup

Tags: boot, xubuntu, webcam

I replaced the Windows 10 OS I previously had on my Lenovo Ideapad laptop with Xubuntu.

A feature of Lenovo laptops is that during boot-time the webcam gets activated for a few seconds (you can tell by the LED light). After installing Xubuntu however the LED light remains on all the time.

The temporary solution I found is disabling the webcam, however I wonder if there is a better solution which would allow me to use the webcam when needed.

Comment: Have you tried this [Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15558/why-does-my-webcam-light-turn-on-when-i-start-up-my-computer-after-standby)